# Can I publish newer version of an existing app in a differnt account and keep the name of the app?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have recently published version 1.0 of an iPhone app in my apple **individual** account. I wish to publish the newer version (1.1) of that app to a new apple **company** account. Is it possible and how? If necessary, I am ready to delete the version 1.0 app from my older account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you'll have to transfer your app to your new account: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html